# Como trabalhar com Foreign Keys no C# ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, combobox

Boa noite, pessoal.

Sou iniciante em C# ASP .NET Core e estou enfrentando problemas com a Foreign Key. Preciso popular um combobox com dados de uma tabela do banco de dados.

A seguir está a minha model Seller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SalesWebMvc.Models {
    public class Seller {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public double basesalary { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
        public Department department { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SalesRecord> sales { get; set; } = new List<SalesRecord>();

        public Seller() {

        }

        public Seller(int id, string name, string email, double basesalary, DateTime birthdate, Department department) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.basesalary = basesalary;
            this.birthdate = birthdate;
            this.department = department;
        }

        public void AddSales(SalesRecord sr) {
            sales.Add(sr);   
        }

        public void RemoveSales(SalesRecord sr) {
            sales.Remove(sr);
        }

        public double TotalSales(DateTime initial, DateTime final) {
            return sales.Where(sr => sr.date >= initial && sr.date <= final).Sum(sr => sr.amount);
        }
    }
}
```

A seguir segue minha model de Department:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SalesWebMvc.Models {
    public class Department {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Seller> sellers { get; set; } = new List<Seller>();

        public Department() {

        }

        public Department(int id, string name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.nome = name;
        }

        public void AddSeller(Seller s) {
            sellers.Add(s);
        }

        public double TotalSales(DateTime initial, DateTime final) {
            return sellers.Sum(seller => seller.TotalSales(initial, final));
        }
    }
}
```

Na view coloquei assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="Seller.DepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
<select asp-for="Seller.DepartmentId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Departments,"Id",
"nome"))" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

Dá erro de integridade referencial!

> MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails

[image: Erro Foreign Key]

Eu gostaria de saber qual a forma mais simples de colocar todos os departamentos dentro de um combobox na View.

Obrigado.

Comment: pelo visto seu erro esta na execução da query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, Lucas, se você estiver usando EntityFramework, criei essa classe base para o contexto para que você herde o seu a partir dela, ou faça a alteração, sobrescrevendo o método OnModelCreating, incluindo convenções para evitar o CASCADE DELETE, que aparentemente está gerando seu erro.

```
public class BaseContexto : DbContext
{
    public BaseContexto()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude.